# appcompat_v7 errors

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I've found out that [Material support library (an updated appcompat-v7) is coming on October 17](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2jd5gl/roman_nurik_material_support_library_an_updated/).
Today I've tried to create an android project, but I've got about 100 errors connected to the Material design. Something like that:

`error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.   styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 168    Android AAPT Problem`

Please, help me, how to resolve this problem?

Comment: You installed 21 SDK, the updated support library in your SDK Manager?

Comment: @jlindenbaum Yes. Should I rollback to 20?

Comment: No idea, it's been so long since I used Eclipse that I can't debug it properly. You've reloaded it, cleaned the project, etc. etc.? I don't think 21 is the problem, seems to be working fine for me on Android Studio.

Comment: @jlindenbaum Yes, I've reloaded eclipse, cleaned the project, tried to add build paths and done other different actions that I've found in the Internet. Nothing works, but setting up the minimum sdk above 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When changing to the API v21 support libraries, you also have to change your build.gradle file to use

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'
```

That fixed it for me.

Build tools version 21.0.1 is a bug fix release that came out late Friday to fix a crash in aapt.exe.

Comment: Thanks! Build tools version 21.0.1 saved me.