# Got error while building android project in new workspace

Tags: android, eclipse

Am new for android development. Am using eclipse for creating android projects. I tried to create a new sample in a newly created workspace with **Target SDK as API 21** and **Compiled with API 19**. I have **installed the SDKs of API 19 and 20 and all its updates**. While **trying to compile** the newly created project I **ended up with the below error**. Can anyone help me how to get rid of this?

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: **Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name** '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.    styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 168    Android AAPT Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.   styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 164    Android AAPT Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'. styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 38 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'. styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 36 Android AAPT Problem
```

and so on.......
I dont know what went wrong. Can anyone guide me in building the project successfully?

Comment: have u update adt so unindtall adt and reinstall adt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt

Answer (score 1):

See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72991#c8 :

> Delete the values-v21 folder on app/src/main/res/, it is not important if you are not using android-L

The above is for Android Studio, For Eclipse it's just in res subfolder of project root.

Also you can try to build with SDK 21, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26437523/1028256 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/24437408/1028256

Seems that the New Project Wizard in Eclipse generated files for SDK 11, including files for appcompat-v7, so you either need to compile with API 21, or remove those files from the project.

Comment: Hi Mixaz, 
I tried deleting the values-21 folder. However I still face the same error as the themes_base.xml still throws error that "No resource found that matches the given name".

Comment: All am left with is to update to Android 5. I have tried all other options. Is there any other way to fix this issue, without updating to Android 5? I need to compile the project in Android 4.4.2 API 19.

Comment: It looks like that Eclipse New Project Wizard created a project for API 21. You can try to re-create a new project with API 19, just to double-check you did everithing correctly. If it doesn't help, I would  try to import any existing project/example into Eclipse, and build it against API 19. There's 'samples' subfolder in Android SDK. I see that samples for android-19 go for Android Studio (gradle build), but android-17 samples appear to be for android-17. Try to import them into Eclipse, it's somewhere in 'File' menu (I'm using Android Studio at the moment)

Comment: I tried opening a new project with Compile version API 19. But ended up in the same error. And all I did is, installed the Android 5 and Build tool 21.0.1 and the errors got cleared. 
However I still have a doubt. I could work on the new projects in the workspace that I created, however If I try importing an existing project to the workspace which has different compile version less than 21, I could not run it. I have created a new workspace and imported the old projects and it worked. Is this problem is because I have appcampat Compiling with 21 in the workspace or Is it a Behavior of eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or similar errors when I tried to compile the GCM Client sample.

I solved it by specifying the correct version in build.gradle. Change:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
}
```

I suppose it's best to set the version number for your dependencies to be the same as your `targetSdkVersion`.

It took me quote some time to figure out and the irony is that Android Studio was already hinting at it: "Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds."

**update**

I just realized you said you "are using Eclipse" which I don't know at all. I suppose you should look for the mechanism where you pull in the app-compat dependency and tell it to use a specific version instead of the newest. Hopefully others can tell you where that is.